# Difference between x>0 and x (as a condition) in python?

Tags: python, montecarlo

What is the difference between the following code snippets? (I'm aware that a negative value of bal will be truthy but why would bal ever be negative?)

```
while spin and bal>0:
    bal = bal - 1
    bal = bal + funciton() #adds either 0 or a positive value to bal
    spin-=1
if (spin==0):
    s=s+1
```

Snippet 2:

```
while spin and bal:
    bal = bal - 1
    bal = bal + funciton() #adds either 0 or a positive value to bal
    spin-=1
if (spin==0):
    s=s+1
```

Comment: The second case bal will be true for any value other than zero. for e.g bal <0

Comment: if you subtract 1 and then add 0 I'm pretty sure you can eventually go below zero

Comment: ^ But won't we reach zero before reaching a negative value? In which case the expression should evaluate to false

Comment: If bal cannot be negative then both are equivalent

Comment: Yeah, but I'm getting an incorrect result for snippet 2

Comment: Under the assumption that `bal` starts as a positive integer and the function returns a non-negative integer, the only difference should be in readability. If you are having problems with this code, try printing all variables at every step to see what's going on.

Comment: To diagnose the failure, we need to see the code that fails.  The posted code hasn't defined `spin` and `bal`, whose values are critical to the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that `bal` is a positive integer from the start and that `function()` returns a positive *integer*, then both code snippets are indeed equivalent.

Although, if `bal` is to be decremented as a counter, you should favor using `bal > 0`. This is both safer and more explicit.

Here is what could go wrong otherwise.

### `bal` could be a float

```
bal = 0.5
while bal:
    bal -= 1
    ...
```

Never will the condition `bal == 0` be fulfilled.

### `bal` could be negative from the start.

```
bal = -1
while bal:
    bal -= 1
    ...
```

Again `bal` will never be falsy since it will always be below `0`.

### `function` could return a float

Adding an `int` and a `float` will yield a `float` and due to [float arithmetic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) it is ill-advised to rely on falsiness of a float.

Here is an example

```
bal = 0.1
bal += 0.2
bal -= 0.3

bal # 5.551115123125783e-17
bool(bal) # True
```

You would mathematically expect `bal` to be zero, although in float arithmetic it is truthy in that case.

Comment: Or `bal` could also be an `np.uint16` that rolls over at 65536, or it could be some crazy user-defined counter type that acts a lot like an integer within the bounds you're expected to use it but is never falsey, or… So yeah, definitely, as your second sentence suggests, write what you mean, don't write something that happens to do the same thing as what you mean under some unstated assumptions…